# cURL isn't running script as a background process

Tags: php, curl

I've been messing around with cURL all day, and can NOT get it to behave in any manner as I've read other people have it working.  No matter how I do it, my entire website hangs until it's finished processing.  I've even tried running it like:

```
exec("curl -d $params $url -k &");
```

It STILL didn't run as a background process.  Now, if I do this in the shell, it's fine.  I'm completely lost now.  I've tried so many methods today and can not get this to run as a background process.  I'm so frustrated right now that it's not working the way it should be that I'm probably missing something small, but I just can't find it.  The code is simple (for now):

```
$url = "path_to_script.php";
$params = "id=$id&etc=etc";
$command = "curl -d \"$params\" \"$url\" -k &";
exec($command);
```

The script that's being called is this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$etc = $_POST['etc'];
$temp = file_get_contents("remote file");
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $temp);
fclose($fp);
```

It works correctly, except that the file_get_contents takes 30+ seconds to complete, and the entire server is frozen until it's done.  This is repeated about 70 times.  Why won't it run as a background process?!?!

Ideally I want to use curl_multi to process them all at the same time, but I **have** to have it run in the background, and am just plain failing to do it properly.

Comment: Did you read the manual? http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

"If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends."

Comment: So basically, you don't want to wait for the response?  Do you NEED the response?

Comment: I'd like the response, but I can make it work without it.  Thanks.

Comment: You can't both have the response and have it run in the background - that would be a contradiction, that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael Mior is right, you need to redirect the output somewhere. If you don't care about where it goes, something like this should do:

```
exec("curl -d $params $url > /dev/null 2>&1");
```